# SQL SERVER 2008 - joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have three tables that I'm trying to join to get the necessary data. Here they are...

```
*TblComp*        *TblCompParent*         *tblCompProcesses*
CompID            CompBillingID           CompID
CompBillingID     Capacity1               CompProcessID
                  Capacity2
```

So what I'm trying to do with these three tables is....

```
Select tblCompParent.Capacity1, tblCompParent.Capacity2, CompProcessID
```

My problem is this...In tblComp there are 351 values - so i start off by joining tblComp and tblCompparent and SELECTING tblCompparent.capacity1, tblcompparent.capacity2, the query looks like this...

```
SELECT dbo.tblComp.CompID, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity1, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity2
FROM dbo.tblCompParents INNER JOIN
dbo.tblComp ON dbo.tblCompParents.CompBillingID = dbo.tblComp.CompBillingID
```

And this works fine, it's when I try to join tblCompProcess to pull the CompProcessID is when I get like 580 records. I'm not sure what can of join I have to do on tblCompprocess to select only one CompProcessID per compID.

And it seems like i have to use tblComp otherwise I'll have no way of joining tblCompProcess.

EDIT1:

```
SELECT dbo.tblComp.CompID, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity1, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity2, tblCompProcess.compprocessID
FROM dbo.tblCompParents INNER JOIN
dbo.tblComp ON dbo.tblCompParents.CompBillingID = dbo.tblComp.CompBillingID
Inner Join dbo.tblCompprocess on tblCompProcess.CompID = tblComp.CompID
```

Comment: you don't show the final sql -- please show the exact sql you are using.  we need to see the one with two joins not just one join.

Comment: Yes you need to join all three tables even if you don't include fields from it into select list.

Comment: Unless tblCompProcesses has a unique constraint on CompID, you may very well have more than one CompProcessID on some of your CompIDs. Given that, do you wish to grab the max or min CompProcessID for each CompID?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev i understand - it seems when i join the third table is when i get weird record count

Comment: @TimLehner no min or max, there's only 1. Even if i was to not grab anything from tblCompProcess, i just want to join the tblCompProcess because later in my query i have criteria WHERE compprocessID = 1110. Just joining the table and not selecting anything still gives me a weird record count

Comment: Read about **Common Table Expressions**. The answer is there.

Comment: @user6576015 Whether or not you select anything from a joined table doesn't affect the number of rows it contributes to the result set. It's always joined. If any pair of join criteria match more than 1 row, all will be returned, and the total row count will increase accordingly. So, if joining a table increases your row count, then that table has >1 row for >= 1 matching row in the other tables. There is no other way this can happen.

Comment: @underscore_d okay so if there are more than 1 value in that table. how do I JOIN it to my query without having my recordcount change. I just want it joined, because i'll be filtering by the CompProcessID

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - your comment about CTE makes no sense -- how do they help?  A sub-query is fine.

Comment: @underscore_d - yes I know that is what he meant but it does a beginner a dis-service to say that the only way to do it is with a CTE.  A CTE or a sub-query will solve this mysterious count issue.

Comment: @Hogan Gah, I deleted to rewrite, never a good idea... but you got what I meant anyway, that the nested join query could alternatively be written as a CTE, albeit with no functional differences. Sure, it's definitely not the only way.

Comment: There seems to be a data duplication problem or some other misunderstanding about the data itself. I don't think it's helpful to suggest technical solutions to simply hide the underlying data problem. Analyze the data in your tblCompProcesses table to eliminate the possibility of non-uniqueness or outright duplicates.

Comment: @TimLehner there are no duplicates. For some CompID's I have different CompProcessID's, i didn't realize it until now. But I'm not trying to select them. I'm only trying to link the table to do a WHERE compProcessID - but I think in that case it won't matter? right? since my query will select that particular record only!

Comment: CTE are so common in current practice that even beginner should learn about it. Everything which can be done with CTE can be done with subquery for sure. And with "no duplicate" situation CTE is the best approach. The only question is how to sort out processId's.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev - kinda hard to do recursion with a sub-query... but *most things* can be done with both.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I do find myself going back to queries I wrote years ago, finding multiple levels of nested `select`s, and wishing I'd known about CTEs then... and when I have enough time, I rewrite them! ...unless I think of a different solution that's better than both, which is often possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us the whole data model so I don't know exactly what is going on but clearly tblCompProcesses has more than one row in your join.  I would fix it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.tblComp.CompID, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity1, dbo.tblCompParents.Capacity2, x.compprocessID
FROM dbo.tblCompParents
INNER JOIN dbo.tblComp ON dbo.tblCompParents.CompBillingID = dbo.tblComp.CompBillingID
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CompID, compprocessID
            FROM dbo.tblCompprocess) X on x.CompID = tblComp.CompID
```

Comment: how would I do this if I wasn't selecting anything from tblCompProcess?

Comment: @user6576015 Again, whether or not you choose to select columns from a joined table, the results are the same - but if you're not selecting anything from it, then why are you joining to it? There might be a valid data reason, but that's not clear at all right now.

Comment: Maybe if you mean **are** selecting other columns from it?  In that case just add them to the sub-query.

Comment: @underscore_d because in that same query, I'll be filtering ex: WHERE compProcessID = 1174

Comment: @user6576015 If you're going to be filtering down to only one `compProcessID`, then why on Earth do you care about the preceding `join` returning multiple matching `compProcessID`s? Perhaps you are thinking about this backwards.

Comment: I was. in one of my earlier comments I realized that i shouldn't care about how many records I get. Thanks!

Comment: @user6576015 Glad to help! It sounds like the way to think about this is that the `where` is 'Here is the `Process` I want to see', and the `join`s are simply scaffolding to get you from that `Process` to your other tables. Whereas it sounds like you were looking at it from the opposite side. To conceptualise things like this, I tend to prefer writing the 'main' table I care about as my `from`, and then join all the others to that. And then, again, to think of `join`s and `where`s as logically separate entities, which really helps.

Comment: @Hogan ...I'm confused. How would the subquery ensure (although, as mentioned, that doesn't actually matter) 1 row from `tblCompProcess` per row from `tblComp`? They were joining on `CompID`, so surely a `select distinct` with that does nothing to change the results.

Comment: @underscore_d you are correct if there are multiple pairs of `CompID, compprocessID` there will still be multiple pairs.  Often when I see this kind of problem there will be only associated value (compprocessID) but multiple rows. My solution will help in those cases but not in the specific case here -- I'll need to know the business rules for which compprocessID to use then I could filter to those results.  I think the OP understood the problem better after posting the question.